# How to specialize a template class method for a specific type?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, sfinae, template-specialization

I have codes like this:

```
class Bar {
 public:
  void print() {
    std::cout << "bar\n";
  }
};

template<typename T>
class Foo {
 public:
  template <typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T,Bar>::value,T>::type>
  void print() {
    t.print();
  }

 template <typename>
  void print() {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
  }
 private:
  T t;
};

int main() {
//  Foo<int> foo1;
  Foo<Bar> foo2;
  foo2.print();
}
```

The purpose of this code is that: If the `T t` is a `Bar` or a subclass of `Bar`, then `foo.print()` is deduced to `void print() {t.print();}`, otherwise deduced to `void print() {std::cout << t << std::endl;}`, but things didn't work as I expect. The compiler errors:

> "a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'typename
>   std::enable_if::value, Bar>::type' (aka
>   'Bar')",

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: After `template <typename` , an identifier is expected. As in `template <typename T>` .Your definition of `print` is not valid C++.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I changed `...::type>` to `...::type* = nullprt>` and it works, but I don't know why write like this.

Comment: You can't name a default for a typename template parameter without an =.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should make both the overloading of `print()` to function template (to make [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) working), otherwise the non-template function is always preferred.
2. You should let `print()` taking its own template type parameter; type cheking shouldn't be performed on the class template parameter `T` directly, function templates overload resolution and SFINAE are performed on the function templates themselves, the class template doesn't involve in.
3. You can move the part of [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to the return type.
4. You should change the order specified to [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) (i.e. `std::is_base_of<Bar, X>`, not `std::is_base_of<X, Bar>`) if you want the type to be `Bar` or the derived class of `Bar`.

e.g.

```
template <typename X = T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Bar, X>::value>::type print() {
  t.print();
}

template <typename X = T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Bar, X>::value>::type print() {
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tGBO7R4ncGoisOVT)

Comment: what if I want keep my function returning void? Or in other cases the return type is fixed?

Comment: @reavenisadesk If you don't specify, the return type is `void` (as my sample code). If you want other types, you can specify explicitly to `std::enable_if`, anyway, the type is fixed.

Comment: Ahh, you came to the same conclusion I did. I see now. I was initially confused because you made it look as if they were standalone functions.

Comment: Hi, another question, in your example, if I change `X` to `T` in `std::is_base_of<X,Bar>`, the code will not compile, what's the difference? Since `typename X = T`?

Comment: @reavenisadesk `std::enable_if` should depend on the template parameter of the function template `print()`'s own; not the one of the class template `Foo`.

Comment: Does that mean template don't "share" template parameters?

Comment: @reavenisadesk if `enable_if` doesn't depend on a template parameter of the `print` function, the compiler expands it immediately and that will result in an error in at least one case. Using the template parameter of the `print` function forces the compiler to wait to expand the return type until it tries to expand the whole `print` template. And since substitution failure is not an error, and there is a version that expanded correctly with no errors, the compiler doesn't flag it as an error.

Comment: @reavenisadesk Function templates overload resolution and SFINAE are performed on the function templates themselves; the class template doesn't involve in.

Comment: @Omnifarious when you mention "expands it immiediately", does that mean the SNINAE is not gonna happen and there's no deduce at all?

Comment: @reavenisadesk - There's no deduction at the time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are actually interested in wether a type has the member function `print` or has defined the `operator<<`, you should also constrain it this way.

With the upcoming `C++20` standard, we are getting [concepts & constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). With that in mind, we can do the following:

```
namespace traits
{
template<typename T>
concept has_print_v = requires(T&& t) { t.print(); };

template<typename T>
concept has_ostream_op_v = requires(T&& t, std::ostream& os) { os << t; };
} // end of namespace traits
```

And use the concepts like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        if constexpr (traits::has_print_v<T>) { t.print(); }
        else if constexpr (traits::has_ostream_op_v<T>) { std::cout << t << "\n"; }
    }
private:
    T t;  
};
```

#### [LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/jTlftB)

Comment: Does any compiler support C++20 yet?

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding template parameter while calling `print()` as it's a template method itself. In any case, your design is overly complicated!

It becomes very simple with C++17, where you need **only one** `Foo<T>::print()` method.

```
void print() {
  if constexpr(std::is_base_of_v<T,Bar>) // ignores `Foo<int>`
    t.print();
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IuEeB51No52mcKho).

Comment: does `if constexpr(std::is_base_of_v<T,Bar>)` really generate a compare command?(asked in efficiency aspect)

Comment: @reavenisadesk, it's very efficient, because `if` condition is evaluated during the compile time. This is as good as what you do using `enable_if` kind of type_traits, but very concise. In nutshell, `if constexpr` is a notebook example for your kind of query. :-)